# Firebase Storage: Allow write/read to authenticated users only?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I have the following code in firebase storage rules section, it basically allows read/write operations on any folder or any folder path to any one as I understand it ..

```
   service firebase.storage {
     match /b/{bucket}/o {
       match /{allPaths=**} {
            allow read, write: if request.auth == null;
       }
     }
    }
```

I have a javascript code that uploads a file to this storage database, code is as follows:

```
// create storage reference
 var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref("Nurse/"+ file.name)

//upload file 
var task = storageRef.put(file)
```

I am able to upload file to the folder 'Nurse' in the storage database.

I want to allow only authenticated users to write/read (upload/download files) at this reference.

My rules code will look as follows I guess:

```
   service firebase.storage {
     match /b/{bucket}/o {
       match /{allPaths=**} {
            allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
       }
     }
    }
```

Now, what kind of Javascript code I need to upload/download files by authenticated users only ..

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

If you have authentication implemented for your project and let's say you would want to authenticate user with email and password, you could do something like

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  // ...
});
```

Once you have authenticated your user, you may use your above code to upload file.

Read more about user authentication over [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/firebaseui). You can implement Google auth, Facebook auth, Github auth, Twitter auth, phone number and custom email login.